# Input inside while and vectors

Tags: c++, loops, vector, cin

This is a noob approach to *vectors*. The following program is really simple, yet i don't understand what i do wrong. It is small so i trust that reading it won't be a trouble. It is supposed to create a vector and add strings to it. Then print the strings on the screen. If the string has been printed, it skips it and goes to the next one. Also, if the string is one of the disliked words (in this case only the word "left"), then it also skips it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string>words;
    string temp,disliked;
    disliked = "left";
    while(cin>>temp)
    {
    words.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
    {
        if(( i==0 || words[i] != disliked && words[i-1]!=words[i]))
        {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

This program is from Stroustrup's book "Programming, principles and practice using c++". I used the code i found in the book and yet when i run the code, the while loop never seems to end. 
What could be wrong with cin>>temp; ?
***Edit***:
When i run the program, the while loop never seems to stop. I have tried "failling" to put a string as input so that the *cin>>temp;* would also fail.
But no matter the type of data i enter as input, the cin never seems to fail. In stroustrup's book the code is exactly like that, which is weird because i encounter logical errors that i cannot pinpoint.
The program was supposed to stop when i enter something other that a string. Then the *while* loop condition would fail, the loop would end and the *for* loop would begin, leaving me with a nice vector and a few strings.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `while(std::cin >> temp)` would loop as far as `std::cin` has not failed. So you obviously haven't triggered a failure condition of `std::cin`, which could be End of File failure, some other read failure or some unexpected stream characters

Comment: _"What could be wrong with cin>>temp; ?"_ What actualy goes wrong with it? Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: It seems you're missing proper scoping. Use a `{}` block to place all the statements that should be executed within the `while()` loop.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Use of

```
if((words[i] != disliked && words[i-1]!=words[i]) || i==0)
```

is a problem since `i == 0` is the second clause of the `||`. `words[-1]` will be accessed before you check that, which causes undefined behavior.

Change it to:

```
if( (words[i] != disliked) && (i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i]))
```

---

To make your code more readable, use `{}` to make the scopes of the blocks a bit clearer.

```
int main()
{
   vector<string>words;
   string temp,disliked;
   disliked = "left";

   cout << "bam" << endl;
   while(cin>>temp)
   {
      words.push_back(temp);
   }
   cout << "bam" << endl;

   for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
   {
      if ( (words[i] != disliked) && (i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i]) )
      {
         cout << words[i] << endl;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```